# SuiteScript - Sublist "Refresh Button"

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

Just wondering if somebody could clearly explain the functionality behind the "Refresh" Button when adding to a sublist on a Suitelet.

What action is triggered when the User clicks this button?

Answer (score 0):

As per NetSuite help: ([NetSuite help link](https://4530345-sb2.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3161033.html#bridgehead_N3161847))

Purpose of refresh button:

> ...to auto-refresh the sublist if its contents are dynamic. In this case, the sublist is refreshed without having to reload the contents of the entire page.

Hope this helps. Please mark this answer as correct if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Does this work only if you have built the sublist with the contents of a saved search?

Comment: Exactly. I have never used the refresh button for anything else other than a saved search.